# Error al abrir página web en local con Ajax (Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:/)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Esto antes funcionaba perfectamente, ahora misteriosamente no lo hace...

Tengo una primera página html con un enlace. Al hacer `click` en el enlace quiero traer contenido de otra página mediante `Ajax` y mostrarlo en un `div` en la primera página.

El fallo lo da en la línea que carga el archivo "contenido-ajax-html":

```
$("#destino").load("contenido-ajax.html");
```

El error que da el navegador Chrome es el siguiente:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/misphp/contenido-ajax.html'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

Si abro el navegador Mozilla funciona correctamente. Antes también funcionaba correctamente con Chrome y ahora no. He probado en dos ordenadores más con Chrome y dan el mismo error...

Este error lo da en local, si lo subo a un servidor se ejecuta correctamente.

¿Por qué no funciona en local?

Gracias

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
  $("#enlaceajax").click(function(evento)
  {
   evento.preventDefault();
   $("#destino").load("contenido-ajax.html");
   //alert("");
  });
 })

</script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#" id="enlaceajax">Haz clic!</a>
<br>
<div id="destino"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tienes que poner un servidor local, por cuestiones de seguridad chrome en sus ultimos patch bloquea las solicitudes que no vengan de un origin valido en este caso: file:///C:/misphp/

Comment: en el servidor donde tengas tu html, en la carpeta de la raíz hay un archivo llamado `.htaccess`. Modifícalo y añade al final del todo una nueva línea con este código `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`guarda el archivo y actualiza, luego pulsa de nuevo en el enlace a ver si carga tu html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que necesita un servidor web para ejecutarse correctamente, si usas Linux puedes instalar Apache y poner tu proyecto en la carpeta `/var/www/html`, y en el navegador ejecutarlo como: `localhost/capeta_proyecto`

También puedes probarlo con Firefox y funcionará; por seguridad, en las nuevas actualizaciones de Google, ya no se permite correr aplicaciones que usan Ajax, JavaScript o JQuery sin un servidor web (que usan protocolo `http`)

Una solución rápida y efectiva puede ser usar la extensión de Chrome `Web server for chrome`, que puedes descargar desde [aquí](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb/related)

Una vez instalada, solo debes escoger el directorio donde tienes tu página web y él lo cargará en ese servidor:

[image: extensión de web server]

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución fue correr todo el sitio en un servidor local usando [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), así:

```sh
npm install http-server -g
# Ir a la carpeta donde están los archivos estaticos. p.ej: cd el/path/a/los/archivos/
http-server
```